# What dose it mean 'regex' on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found this too code in one example script:

```
'regex':'^[a-zA-Z]{2} *\\d{6}|[a-zA-Z]{2} *\\d{3} *[a-zA-Z]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}|[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{5}|[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{5}|[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[a-zA-Z]{1}|[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}$',
```

but i really do not know what it means...

Comment: Did you search for 'regex' at all? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: If you can reach the person who wrote this, ask him. Decoding regular expressions is a pain in the ass. Otherwise, try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253884/regex-decoder-tool

Comment: Regex - *Regular Expression* Regex isn't only used in JavaScript. It's used quite widely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is a regular expression for example disecting parts of text from a bigger collection of text.
Say for example that you want to find all names in a newspaper. Instead of reading the entire thing looking for each name you can make a regex model of finding every word starting with a capital letter that is not right after a punctuation.

In your example the regex ^ means it looks for something that starts with the following:
 - A small or capital letter between a to z
 - The word is to letters long

Read a couple of examples and you'll get the hang of it.

http://www.dreambank.net/regex.html

It is simply just a model how text is built up.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the explanation of the posted regex, you should try [regex101](http://regex101.com) . It breaks down the posted regex into capture groups and gives a pretty detailed explanation and matches for a given input and regex.

Like many have already suggested, it would be better if you start by reading about how regex works. I'm sure you'll find [plenty of related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) on Stackoverflow.

However, I have created a [simple demo](http://regex101.com/r/sG4jR6/1) of your posted regex on regex101 like I said. I'm going to refrain from posting the entire explanation here. it would be a good exercise if you try to read the explanation and understand it on your own.